# Excel Drop Down List

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

I'm making a chart that contains drop downs per each day and i have it setup where the first row has two options: √ or X. and the second row holds numbers as an option. I want to be able to switch from √, X, to 12,11,10... without having to constantly separate things. When I pull that cell it just returns all of those number on 1 line and doesn't separate them.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GrIX.png)How can I have my drop down pull from one cell in the source field? Naturally it wants a 1 cell or multiple for a series of words or numbers. I have a formula that returns a series of numbers in once cell: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GrIX.png)

[image]

[1][image]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1L2z.png

Comment: Would you mind being more descriptive of expected results? What cells are you using for source and what values are expecting to show for the given source?

Comment: I'm making a chart that contains drop downs per each day and i have it setup where the first row has two options: √ or X. and the second row holds numbers as an option. I want to be able to switch from √, X, to 12,11,10... without having to constantly separate things. When I pull that cell it just returns all of those number on 1 line and doesn't separate them.

Comment: Ah, that sort of helps. I guess it's just not clicking with me based on the picture you provided. Are you saying A:A can either have a checkmark or X, and B:B only holds numbers, but optionally? And you want C:C to pick from either of those columns?

Comment: I added another image, hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think the infrastructure you built isn't suitable for your objective. Therefore my "solution" might not suit your problem. But it's nice. Please take a look.

I use the range F6:W17 as a source for the drop-down lists. And I need a cell somewhere that specifies which list is to be selected. I named the list source `DList` and numbered the rows from 1 and up, each numbered row containing the list of one drop-down. I chose A1 as the cell to specify the list. A 7 entered in A1 specified the drop-down list in row 7 of the `DList` range. The location of `DList` is immaterial.

Here is the formula that specifies the drop-down list in the data validation.

```
=OFFSET(INDEX(DList,1,1),$A$1-1,0,1,COUNTA(INDEX(DList,$A$1,0)))
```

*INDEX(DList,1,1)* specifies the first cell of the named range. It's the cell from where the OFFSET function counts everything.

*$A$1-1,0* specifies the offset from the first specified cell (which is the first cell in the source range). $A$!-1 specifies the row. The first row of `DList` has the #1 in A1 but the offset from the first row of `DList` to row #1 is zero. Hence $A$1-1.

*1,COUNTA(INDEX(DList,$A$1,0)* specifies the number of rows and columns of the range being specified. There is always only 1 row, the one specified by the offset, and the number of columns is equal to the number of entries in that row. This ensures that there will be no blank entries in your drop-down so long as all blanks are at the end of the row.

I couldn't make out how you intend to specify the drop-down but I imagine that the functionality of A1 can either be taken over by another cell you specify (I would prefer to name the cell rather than use the address), or you might enter a formula in A1 (or whatever cell takes its place) that picks the correct number needed by the validation formula.

Comment: i wish i could've uploaded the file! Not the best at explaining it. I just want the drop down to be defined by a result. When it retrieves the result it keeps that format even if it contains commas. I want it to retrieve that once cell and use the commas in the value to generate more options.

Comment: If you want to close in on what you want you should test my solution and tell me what it is that it doesn't do. That would give you a new chance to describe your requirement from a different perspective. Your above comment throws that chance to the wind.